# Separating list of data in Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, chart.js

I have a list that contains 4 data from a python script that is being called by an Ajax function. I cannot figure out the method to separate it. The reason I need it to be separated is because each data will be sent to separate Chartjs to be displayed. The existing ajax functions take single data from separate functions from python script which I want to replace with the latest ajax and python script.

This is my html page function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chart.js demo</title>
    <!-- import plugin script -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-rmZcZsyhe0/MAjquhTgiUcb4d9knaFc7b5xAfju483gbEXTkeJRUMIPk6s3ySZMYUHEcjKbjLjyddGWMrNEvZg=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-streaming@latest/dist/chartjs-plugin-streaming.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div style="height: 450px; width: 450px; display: inline-block">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="height: 450px; width: 450px; display: inline-block">
    <canvas id="myChart2" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="height: 450px; width: 450px; display: inline-block">
    <canvas id="myChart4" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="height: 450px; width: 450px; display: inline-block">
    <canvas id="myChart5" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="height: 450px; width: 450px; display: inline-block">
    <canvas id="myChart3" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    //the ajax function I want to use
    function monitor() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                data = this.responseText;

                chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                    dataset.data.push({
                        x: Date.now(),
                        y: data,
                    });
                });
            }

        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "getmonitor", true);
        xhttp.send();

        return disp;
    }
</script>

<script>
    //the existing ajax
    function cpuDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var disp = {x: Date.now(), y: 25.7};


        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                cp = this.responseText;

                chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                    dataset.data.push({
                        x: Date.now(),
                        y: cp,
                    });
                });
            }

        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "getcpu", true);
        xhttp.send();

        return disp;
    }


    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets:
                [{
                    label: "CPU Percentage",
                    data: [],
                    borderColor: "#d7041c",
                    fill: false
                }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                fill: true
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'CPU'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Time'
                    },
                    type: 'realtime',
                    realtime: {
                        duration: 10000,
                        delay: 10000,
                        refresh: 1000,
                        onRefresh: memoryDoc()
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        steps: 20,
                        max: 100,
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Percentage'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>


<script>
    //the existing ajax
    function memoryDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var disp = {x: Date.now(), y: 25.7};

        xhttp.open("GET", "getmem", true);
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                mm = this.responseText;


                chart2.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                    dataset.data.push({
                        x: Date.now(),
                        y: mm,
                    });
                });
            }

        };

        return disp;
    }


    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
    var chart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets:
                [{
                    label: "Memory Percentage",
                    data: [],
                    borderColor: "#0a2dae",
                    fill: false
                }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Memory'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Time'
                    },
                    type: 'realtime',
                    realtime: {
                        duration: 10000,
                        delay: 10000,
                        refresh: 1000,
                        onRefresh: memoryDoc
                    },
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        steps: 20,
                        max: 100,
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Percentage'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<script>
    //the existing ajax
    function networkIn() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var disp = {x: Date.now(), y: 25.7};

        xhttp.open("GET", "getib", true);
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                ib = this.responseText;


                chart4.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                    dataset.data.push({
                        x: Date.now(),
                        y: ib,
                    });
                });
            }

        };

        return disp;
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart4').getContext('2d');
    var chart4 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets:
                [{
                    label: "Inbound",
                    data: [],
                    borderColor: "#d7c204",
                    fill: false
                }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Network Usage'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Time'
                    },
                    type: 'realtime',
                    realtime: {
                        duration: 10000,
                        delay: 10000,
                        refresh: 1000,
                        onRefresh: networkIn
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        steps: 20,
                        max: 100,
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'MBPS'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>


<script>
    //the existing ajax
    function networkOut() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var disp = {x: Date.now(), y: 25.7};

        xhttp.open("GET", "getob", true);
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                ob = this.responseText;


                chart5.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                    dataset.data.push({
                        x: Date.now(),
                        y: ob,
                    });
                });
            }

        };

        return disp;
    }


    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart5').getContext('2d');
    var chart5 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets:
                [{
                    label: "Outbound",
                    data: [],
                    borderColor: "#5fd913",
                    fill: false
                }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Network Usage'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Time'
                    },
                    type: 'realtime',
                    realtime: {
                        duration: 10000,
                        delay: 10000,
                        refresh: 1000,
                        onRefresh: networkOut
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        steps: 20,
                        max: 100,
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'MBPS'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>


<script>
    //the existing ajax
    setInterval(loadDoc3, 900000)

    function loadDoc3() {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "getdk", true);
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                dk = this.responseText;

            }
        };

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "getdkf", true);
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                dkf = this.responseText;

            }
        };

        dss = [dk, dkf];

        chart3.data.datasets.pop({
            data: dss
        });
        chart3.update();

        chart3.data.datasets.push({
            data: dss
        });
        chart3.update();


    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart3').getContext('2d');
    var chart3 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Used", "Free"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Disk Usage",
                backgroundColor: ["#8a0404", "#177000"],
                data: [0, 0],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Disk Usage'
            },
            elements: {
                arc: {
                    backgroundColor: ["#8a0404", "#177000"]
                }
            },
        },

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The get monitor returns the list of data from views.py as below:

```
# load html page to display Chartjs
def cpu_monitor(request):
    # execute the call function upon loading chart.html
    # call()

    return render(request, "chart.html")


# gather data from Flask for cpu, memory and network usage
def monitor(request):
    # request data from Flask
    url1 = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/cpu"
    url2 = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/memory"
    url3 = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/inb"
    url4 = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/oub"

    # storing received data
    cpu_data = requests.get(url1)
    memory_data = requests.get(url2)
    ib_data = requests.get(url3)
    ob_data = requests.get(url4)

    # converting stored data to json format
    cpu_data2 = cpu_data.json()
    memory_data2 = memory_data.json()
    ib_data2 = ib_data.json()
    ob_data2 = ob_data.json()

    # extracting only the value of the received data
    for key in cpu_data2:
        cpu_value = cpu_data2['CPU']
        time = cpu_data2['Time']
        print(cpu_value)
        print(time)

    for key in memory_data2:
        memory_value = memory_data2['Memory Percentage']
        time = memory_data2['Time']
        print(memory_value)
        print(time)

    for key in ib_data2:
        inbound_value = ib_data2['Received Bytes']
        time = ib_data2['Time']
        print(inbound_value)
        print(time)

    for key in ob_data2:
        outbound_value = ob_data2['Received Bytes']
        time = ob_data2['Time']
        print(outbound_value)
        print(time)

    # storing the extracted values into dictionary
    monitorData = [cpu_value, memory_value, inbound_value, outbound_value]

    # returning the dictionary
    return HttpResponse(monitorData)
```

Comment: Where are the separate charts?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I have edited the codes

Comment: Where are the four pieces of data?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Edited it in

Answer (score 0):

You need to have charts as separate entities:

```js
// Put all the instances of Chart into a single array
let charts = [chart1, chart2, ... ]

// when the data comes back, do the following:
let data = [80, 70, ... ] // example data

data.map((value, index) => {
   let chart = charts[index];
   // assign data to chart
   chart.data = value;
})
```

Comment: Should all these be done in the function monitor() or elsewhere? Also, let data should consist [getMonitor] or [cpu_value, memory_value, inbound_value, outbound_value]

Comment: The second. But isn't `[cpu_value, memory_value, inbound_value, outbound_value] == getMonitor` ?

Comment: I tried it for one of the chart for cpu reading but the chart disappeared from my web page. I edited the new codes into the question. Where did I do it wrong?

Comment: The myChart stuff needs to be `let myChart = new Chart(....)` stuff

Comment: Still the same, no chart appearing. I have edited the codes in question with the latest changes

Comment: Im not familiar with the exact library youre using. Look for errors and use a debugger to find whats going wrong.

Comment: I managed to get the chart to appear however no data is being displayed. Just an empty chart.

Comment: The wrong I posted is there to handle the response of the XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Your call to getmonitor returns data. The data needs to be mapped onto the charts, after you get it.